# Compiled expressions run much slower than interpreted versions

Tags: c#, performance, jit, precompiled

I have a rules engine, which supports two modes of operations:

1. Compilation into a C# program and linked into the engine
2. Parsing into a reverse-polish stack-based instructions and interpreted

The rules are simple arithmetical expressions with function calls (max, min, sin, cos etc.)

I would have assumed the compiled version (i.e. #1) to be **much** faster than the interpreted version (i.e. #2) -- in fact, that's the main reason for having a compiled mode in the first place.  However, my speed tests showed otherwise.

### Compiled Version

```
Action<double>[] Rules = new[] { calc1, calc2, calc3 ... };
double[] v = new double[...];   // Variables

void calc1(double arg) { v[3]=v[12]+v[15]/v[20] };   // "x3=x12+x15/x20"
void calc2(double arg) { ... };
   :
// Start timer now
Rules.AsParallel().ForAll(r => r(...));
// End timer
```

### Interpreted Version

```
Expression[] Rules = ...
// Each rule is already parsed into an Expression object, which is a set of
// reverse-polish stack-based instructions.
// For example, "x3=x12+x15/x20" will be parsed to:
//     [ Push(12), Push(15), Push(20), Divide(), Add() ]
// Start timer now
Rules.AsParallel().ForAll(r => r.Evaluate(...));
// End timer
```

Here, "Expression" is part of a third-party library that parses a simple string into a simple set of reverse-polish stack-based instructions, which can then be interpreted.  It is *not* the expression-tree object in LINQ -- just for clarification.

*Note: don't worry about concurrency since in the real code, I sort the rules by "layers" and calculate the layers sequentially, which each layer only depending on values calculated in previous layers.  Both modes have the exact same layers structure.*

### The Results

Shockingly, the interpreted version runs **MUCH** faster than the compiled version, average a factor of 4x!  In other words, the compiled version took 0.3s to run through around 1,200 rules, while the interpreted version took on average 0.08-0.1s.

My computer is a so-so dual-core Core2.

I am using .NET 4.0, Visual Studio 10.

Performance is similar in Debug or Release builds.

### My Question

What can be causing the significant slowdown in the compiled mode?

**NOTE: I HAVE POSTED ONE POSSIBLE ANSWER**

Comment: What is the "Evaluate" method here? I can't see it on MSDN for Expression.

Comment: Does Expression *have* an `Evaluate` method? I don't think we can say much meanigfully unless we have something runnable we can look at...

Comment: also, note that most code "running" an expression is actually compiling it - so it isn't really interpreted, although there may be some overhead of compilation. But ultimately it is hard to say much without a full example

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  "Expression" is a custom library to parse expressions.  It parses an expression into reverse-polish stack-based simple instruction, which are then interpreted.

Comment: sorry, need a bit more detail on the rules and how they are run interpreted. i.e. could you expand some of the ellipsises

Comment: Eliminate the parallel processing and process the rules sequentially. Can you still reproduce those differences?

Comment: Are you using reflection and in what manner?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth, setting parallelism to anything (from 1 to 4) does not affect the run times.

Comment: @Bueller, no reflection used.

Comment: I would still suggest, to use an ordinary foreach loop, just to remove one variable from the equation.

Comment: I think I have found the answer.  I'll post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET is a JIT-compiled environment, so the more code to JIT-compile, the slower it is.  It can be that 1,200 methods are JIT-compiled at run-time at the point of execution, vs. in the interpreted mode only the interpreter is JIT-compiled, once.  I may be seeing extra JIT times in my loops for the compiled mode.

Experiment:

1. Run each mode 5 times (just to complete any JIT compilation and fill caches)
2. Time 50 runs, take the average

Results:

1. Compiled mode: 1.6ms per run
2. Interpreted mode: 5.3ms per run

Observations:

It appears that a large amount of time is spent during the **FIRST** run of the compiled mode.

The **SECOND** run of the compiled mode is already similar in speed to the interpreted mode.

The interpreted mode does not speed up significant with the number of runs.

Thus suggesting my point of view that the rule code is JIT-compiled during the first run.

Comment: Regular .NET methods are JIT compiled as needed, so the first time a method is invoked there's an overhead associated with the compilation.